# How can i give Google spreadsheet standard values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to give my spreadsheet standard values like : Name, Surname , Email. And with a colour if possible.

Comment: You need to be more elaborate.

Comment: You also need to post the code you wrote so far or what apis you are having trouble

Answer (score 0):

As previously said it's hardly enough info to answer it properly. But I'll try to guess it:

If you would like to choose from standard values, you should add Validation to the cells. (Data menu Validation, and you can add Criterias there.)

Also if you would like to color the cells based on a specific value, you should use Format menu Condtitional formatting.

If that's not what you've asked for, please specify your questions more.